# Using IIS only allow automatic windows authentication and disable manually entered user credentials

Tags: iis, active-directory, single-sign-on, kerberos, ntlm

Is it possible to disable the login modal prompt that appears in browsers when automatic windows authenticate fails and then just redirect users to a 401 page? I want to be able to only allow automatic logins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't something you can configure on the server. The IE automatically pops that screen when Kerberos and NTLM has beeen rejected by the server.